# How to remove bullet point when printing errors that are tied to base in rails 4 application?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a custom validator in a ROR 4 app which checks for a condition and then adds a custom error message to base:

```
errors.add(:base, "Please enter email as well as your city")
```

When the error displays on the screen, it has a bullet point in it. Can I remove the bullet point as the error is for the whole form and not a particular field? I do not want a generic css rule which removes bullet points from all errors added to base across the app. I want to remove the bullet point from only that particular form. Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: So **do you** or **don't you** want all errors added to base to have bullet points removed?  Your title says you do but your post says you don't (in which case I am not sure what you want).

Comment: I do, but only for that particular form. I do not want a css rule that removes bullet points from errors that are added to base across all forms of the app. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my post.